# C# specifying difference between parent class vs interface

Tags: c#

In C# you specify the parent class for inheritance the same way you specify an interface with the ":" after the class definition

public class MyClass : ParentClass

public class MyClass : SimpleInterface

So, how can you tell when the item after the colon is a parent class vs an interface?

Comment: Generally interfaces are prefixed with "I". `male : Person` vs `male : IPerson`

Comment: If it is an interface, you'll know when you try to build your code and haven't implemented the interface methods.  Also, visual studio intellisense should be able to tell you by hovering over `ParentClass` or `SimpleInterface`

Comment: It's also color coded in VS

Comment: or use 'Peek Definition'

Comment: "Who can toy tell" tell when? do you mean while writing code or compiling or run time?

Comment: Are you doing reverse engineering on code that is written by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

The rule is to start names of interfaces with a capital I and the first letter of the name after the I also a capital letter: `IDictionary`, `IList`. This pattern is easy to recognize and should be followed.

Furthermore:

- A class can have only one base class, but implement multiple interfaces. Everything after a comma is necessarily an interface: `class Subclass : Baseclass, IInterface1, IInterface2`
- Interface identifiers are colored differently in most modern IDEs
- Most modern IDEs provide this information on mouse hover or with a "goto definition" command

Regarding the "specifying difference" in the question title, this is specified in the declaration. Even if you deviate from the naming conventions, you cannot have an interface and a class or struct of the same name in the same namespace. There is no need to make a distinction by syntax in the inheritance list of a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the name after the : then press <kbd>F12</kbd>. VS will jump to the declaration of it. If you read in the declaration the word `interface` then your suspect is an interface. Otherwise it will be a class

Answer (score -1):

Other than what been suggested, You can use the [`IsInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinterface?view=netframework-4.7.2) property like

```
typeof(MyClass).BaseType.IsInterface
```